# Как сделать запрос и обработать результат, игнорируя создание mp3 файла?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, распознавание-речи, синтезатор-речи

Я делаю телеграмм бота и мне нужно было синтезировать текст в аудио, я отправлял запрос на yandex.cloud и в ответ получаю response.data:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
const cfg = {
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': `Api-Key ${config.yandex_api_key}`
    }
};

const data = {
    text: 'Привет, мир!',
    lang: 'ru-RU',
    voice: 'madirus',
    speed: 1.0,
    format: 'mp3'
};

axios.post('https://tts.api.cloud.yandex.net/speech/v1/tts:synthesize', data, cfg)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
        });`
```

Как можно было бы это обработать и отправить через телеграмм бота без создание mp3 файла?

Comment: то, что вы нарисовали на картинке, весьма похоже на аудио-запись. вероятно, вам надо бы расшифровать смысл, который вы вкладываете в слова «обработать и отправить».

Comment: думаю, проще всего будет указать в вызове axios `responseType: 'stream'` и передать полученный stream в метод sendAudio

Comment: Я немного не понимаю, что именно нужно передавать в ответе с responseType: 'stream', потому что там передаётся огромный ответ и data в которой `ID3\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00#TSSE\x00\x00\x00\x0F\x00\x00\x03Lavf57.56.100\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00��T�\x00\x00��\ и т.д`. Если попытаться ее передать то получаю ошибку.